# Accessing PIN protected data on SmartCard (ISO 7816-4) using APDU commands

Tags: javascript, smartcard, apdu

I'm a newbie on SmartCard related questions and I’m facing some issues and need some help to overcome them.

I need to read some data from a PT CitizenCard, part of this data such name, photo, etc., is public access, on other hand data like address is PIN protected. What I know about that content:

- 3F 00 - public DF / MF
- 5F 00 - public DF / DF
- EF 02 (public data) | EF0F | EF08 (certificates)
- EF 05 address (PIN protected)

**For accessing this data I’m using the following APDU commands / instructions:**

```
  sendAPDUCommand(scContext, cardContext, "00A4040007604632FF000002"); // Select card
  sendAPDUCommand(scContext, cardContext, "00A4000C023F00"); // Public DF / MF
  sendAPDUCommand(scContext, cardContext, "00A4000C025F00"); // Public DF / DF 
  sendAPDUCommand(scContext, cardContext, "00A4000C02" + EF_VALUE); // Select EF
```

Where EF_VALUE takes the value of **EF02 | EF0F | EF08** according needs

For reading EF data segments I’m using the instruction:

```
// some other code here …

let segmentData;
for (let j = 0; j < max_value + 1; j++) {
   let segment = j.toString(16).padStart(2, "0").toUpperCase()
   segmentData = await sendAPDUCommand(scContext, cardContext, "00B0" + segment + "0000");
   // some other code here
   if (segmentData["returnCode"] == "9000") {
     data += segmentData["value"];
   }
   // some other code here (error handle, etc)
}

// some other code here …
```

For reading citizen Address data on smartcard, I'm basically using the same instructions/commands, for public data, with EF -> **EF05**.
Address data is PIN protected, so I’m trying to previously execute a 'Verify' protocol that consists on validate Address PIN before try to obtain / read that data from the card, just like I’m doing on signing data procedure by AuthenticationCertificatePIN.

Address PIN is validated OK, but reading data procedure returns:
SW1: 69
SW2: 82
(Security condition not satisfied)

Can any one help with that question?

I'm trying to use that code snippet on description, but no results... :( and I'm expecting that anyone can instructs me how can I solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: "PT" stands for Portugal? You are aware of the difference of `"00B0"`and `"\x00\xB0"`? How sure are you, that you verified he correct PIN? (Because the response would exactly fit to having verified a wrong PIN number or wrong PIN value)?

Comment: Hi, guidot. Yes, PT stands for Portugal the 00B0 works fine to the other components that are using the same method for reading EF page such as public data (no PIN protected). The PIN is the right one.

Comment: I think that sequence named "following APDU commands / instructions" resets security flags because of select application. You can have 6982 if you verify PIN before select app.